# Using JSON_MODIFY(), how do I append a string to the root path when its name is unknown or is unspecified?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I want to append to the root of a JSON string, when no other root is specified, or its name is unknown.  Unfortunately, some other root node *must* be specified before I can append another JSON node.  How do I append additional JSON structures when no other root is specified, or its root name is unknown?

First, I start off with an empty JSON object/string.  `JSON_MODIFY()` cannot deal with an empty string `''`:

`declare @jsonResponse nvarchar(max) = '{}';`

Then, I populate the response:

```
select @jsonResponse = (
        select
            'stuff' as colA
            ,'stuff' as colB
            ,'stuff' as colC
        for json path, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES 
);
```

If I try to APPEND to `@jsonResponse` like this:

```
set @jsonResponse =  json_modify(@jsonResponse, 'append $."Added Stuff"', 'some more stuff'); --no error, but no append
--set @jsonResponse =  json_modify(@jsonResponse, 'append $.[0]', 'some more stuff'); --error
--set @jsonResponse =  json_modify(@jsonResponse, 'append $[0]', 'some more stuff'); --no error, but no append
--set @jsonResponse =  json_modify(@jsonResponse, 'append [0].$', 'some more stuff'); --error
--set @jsonResponse =  json_modify(@jsonResponse, 'append [0]$', 'some more stuff'); --error
```

**None of these work**.  The only one that doesn't produce an error is the first & third example `'append $."Added Stuff"'`.  This is all I get:

`[{"colA":"stuff","colB":"stuff","colC":"stuff"}]`

**HOWEVER** If I specify a root path in my original select statement (which is undesired), **THEN** I'll be able to append other JSON structures later on:

```
select @jsonResponse = (

        select
            'stuff' as colA
            ,'stuff' as colB
            ,'stuff' as colC
        for json path, root('root'), INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES 

)

set @jsonResponse =  json_modify(@jsonResponse, 'append $."Added Stuff"', 'some more stuff')
```

Result:

`{"root":[{"colA":"stuff","colB":"stuff","colC":"stuff"}],"Added Stuff":["some more stuff"]}`

**==DESIRED RESULT==**

I want to append content to my JSON string, at will, even if that string has no root `[{"key":"val"}]`, or its root is unknown `{"RootNameUnknown": []}`, or it's an empty object `{}`.

I cannot (or do not know how to) append to a pre-established JSON string unless it already has a root, and one of the roots is known.  Another issue is, you cannot modify the JSON string unless you've pre-established it as `{}`

So, a desired results might looks something like this:

```
{
"SomeRoot": [
    {
        "colA": "stuff",
        "colB": "stuff",
        "colC": "stuff"
    }
],
"ExampleAppend1": [
    "content"
],
"ExampleAppend2": [
    {
        "speedracer": "go"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Please include the desired result.

Comment: An example of a desired result is shown at the bottom, something like:  `{"root":[{"colA":"stuff","colB":"stuff","colC":"stuff"}],"Added Stuff":["some more stuff"]}`

Comment: But you said: "If I specify a root path in my original select statement (which is undesired)".  So is that the desired result or not?

Comment: I want to append content to a JSON string when that string has no root `[{"key":"val"}]`, or its root is unknown `{"nameUnknown": []}`.  I cannot (or do not know how to) append to a pre-established JSON string *unless* it already has a root, and one of the roots is known.

Comment: Type, in the body of your question, the JSON document you want as the result.

Comment: okay, updated to reflect desired request

Comment: Can you assume that the top-level of the input is an object `{. . .}` , not an array `[ ... ]`, or a literal?

Comment: That's a GREAT question.  In this specific scenario, it appears that I'm trying to append to an array.  1) the first select creates an array of objects, then, 2) I want to append root-level content to that array of objects.  I suppose pre-declaring an empty object `{}` in this scenario has no meaning, and is overwritten.

Comment: I will update the desired result.... I suppose the outer shell should be an array.

Comment: Actually !!!  In order to be considered "valid JSON", the outer shell should be an object. `{}`.  Although, an array `[]` is technically valid too, but the innards would probably need to be rearranged... To answer your question, YES, assume an object `{}`

Comment: In JSON the top level can be any `value`, and a value is an object, array, string, number, "true","false", or "null".  See https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: @raydlevel5 It's very important what is the actual structure of your initial JSON - 1) `FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('root')` generates a JSON object with one JSON array as single property; 2)`FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` generates a JSON object with three scalar values as properties, 3)`FOR JSON PATH` generates a JSON array with one JSON object as single item. `JSON_MODIFY() `depends on this JSON structure.and the results are different.

Comment: I think you are all trying to tell me that you cannot append data to an unamed array.

Comment: @raydlevel5 Yes, I made an update in the answer with some explanations. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Explanations:**

I'm not sure if this is an exact answer to your question, but it's too long for a comment. It's important to mention, that `FOR JSON PATH` returns different JSON content depending on the `ROOT` and `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` options. The following table shows the different JSON output:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
|Statement                              | Result                                                    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
| SELECT                                | [{"colA":"stuff","colB":"stuff","colC":"stuff"}]          |
|   'stuff' AS colA,                    | JSON array                                                | 
|   'stuff' AS colB,                    |                                                           |
|   'stuff' AS colC                     |                                                           |
| FOR JSON PATH                         |                                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
| SELECT                                | {"colA":"stuff","colB":"stuff","colC":"stuff"}            |
|   'stuff' AS colA,                    | JSON object                                               | 
|   'stuff' AS colB,                    |                                                           |
|   'stuff' AS colC                     |                                                           |
| FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER  |                                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
| SELECT                                | {"root":[{"colA":"stuff","colB":"stuff","colC":"stuff"}]} |
|   'stuff' AS colA,                    | JSON object                                               | 
|   'stuff' AS colB,                    |                                                           |
|   'stuff' AS colC                     |                                                           |
| FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('root')           |                                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, if you want to append content to a JSON string using `JSON_MODIFY()`, you need to use an appropriate combination of `path` expression and `append` modifier.

**Append content to JSON text generated with `FOR JSON PATH`**:

```
DECLARE @jsonResponse nvarchar(max)
SELECT @jsonResponse = (
   SELECT 'stuff' AS colA, 'stuff' AS colB, 'stuff' AS colC
   FOR JSON PATH
)
SELECT @jsonResponse = JSON_MODIFY(
   @jsonResponse,
   'append $',
   'some more stuff'
)
```

Result:

```
[{"colA":"stuff","colB":"stuff","colC":"stuff"},"some more stuff"]
```

**Append content to JSON text generated with `FOR JSON PATH`, `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` and `append` modifier**:

```
DECLARE @jsonResponse nvarchar(max)
SELECT @jsonResponse = (
   SELECT 'stuff' AS colA, 'stuff' AS colB, 'stuff' AS colC
   FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
)
SELECT @jsonResponse = JSON_MODIFY(
   @jsonResponse,
   'append $."Added Stuff"',
   'some more stuff'
)
```

Result:

```
{"colA":"stuff","colB":"stuff","colC":"stuff","Added Stuff":["some more stuff"]}
```

**Append content to JSON text generated with `FOR JSON PATH`, `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` and without `append` modifier**:

```
DECLARE @jsonResponse nvarchar(max)
SELECT @jsonResponse = (
   SELECT 'stuff' AS colA, 'stuff' AS colB, 'stuff' AS colC
   FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
)
SELECT @jsonResponse = JSON_MODIFY(
   @jsonResponse,
   '$."Added Stuff"',
   'some more stuff'
)
```

Result:

```
{"colA":"stuff","colB":"stuff","colC":"stuff","Added Stuff":"some more stuff"}
```

**Append content to JSON text generated with `FOR JSON PATH` and `ROOT`**:

```
DECLARE @jsonResponse nvarchar(max)
SELECT @jsonResponse = (
   SELECT 'stuff' AS colA, 'stuff' AS colB, 'stuff' AS colC
   FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('root')
)
SELECT @jsonResponse = JSON_MODIFY(
   @jsonResponse,
   'append $."Added Stuff"',
   'some more stuff'
)
```

Result:

```
{"root":[{"colA":"stuff","colB":"stuff","colC":"stuff"}],"Added Stuff":["some more stuff"]}
```